# Gridgain Notify Listener not working for GridEvent - what do i need to configure?

Tags: grid-computing, gridgain

Here's another issue I've come across when trying to port our codebase from gridgain 4 to gridgain 6. 
Anyway, The intent is to wire in a one of our listeners to perform certain actions upon detection of a grid event (such as EVT_NODE_JOINED)

In the old code, we wire'd in our listener (gridNodeMonitor) as described by this xml snippet.

```
<beans profile="master">
    <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.GridSpringBean">
        <property name="configuration">
            <bean parent="abstractGridConfiguration">
                <property name="userAttributes">
                    <map merge="true">
                        <entry key="com.mycompany.master" value="true"/>
                    </map>
                </property>
                <property name="lifecycleBeans">
                    <list>
                        <ref bean="gridNodeMonitor"/>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="localEventListeners">
                    <map>
                        <entry key-ref="gridNodeMonitor">
                            <list>
                                <util:constant static-field="org.gridgain.grid.GridEventType.EVT_NODE_JOINED"/>
                                <util:constant static-field="org.gridgain.grid.GridEventType.EVT_NODE_LEFT"/>
                                <util:constant static-field="org.gridgain.grid.GridEventType.EVT_NODE_FAILED"/>
                                <util:constant static-field="org.gridgain.grid.GridEventType.EVT_NODE_RECONNECTED"/>
                            </list>
                        </entry>
                    </map>
                </property>
                <property name="topologySpi">
                    <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.topology.nodefilter.GridNodeFilterTopologySpi">
                        <property name="filter">
                            <bean class="com.mycompany.enterprise.gridgain.license.GridNodeMonitorImpl"
                                  factory-method="createTopologyFilter">
                                <constructor-arg ref="gridNodeMonitor"/>
                            </bean>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="cacheConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.cache.GridCacheConfigurationAdapter"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

In the new code, the configuration schema has changed and this is what I've ported it to (localEventListener isn't a valid property anymore). I'm guessing my issue is that I haven't specified a listener  to monitor the events. How should I configure this? I should note that in any case, GridGain works correctly, i.e. jobs are being distributed to the correct nodes, it's just the listener that isn't correctly being registered.

Thanks

```
<beans profile="master">
    <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.GridSpringBean">
        <property name="configuration">
            <bean parent="abstractGridConfiguration">
                <property name="userAttributes">
                    <map merge="true">
                        <entry key="com.mycompany.master" value="true"/>
                    </map>
                </property>
                <property name="lifecycleBeans">
                    <list>
                        <ref bean="gridNodeMonitor"/>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="includeEventTypes">
                    <list>
                        <util:constant static-field="org.gridgain.grid.events.GridEventType.EVT_NODE_JOINED"/>
                        <util:constant static-field="org.gridgain.grid.events.GridEventType.EVT_NODE_LEFT"/>
                        <util:constant static-field="org.gridgain.grid.events.GridEventType.EVT_NODE_FAILED"/>
                        <util:constant static-field="org.gridgain.grid.events.GridEventType.EVT_NODE_RECONNECTED"/>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="cacheConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.cache.GridCacheConfiguration"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks correct to me. Have you added a listener in the code, like so:

```
GridPredicate<GridTaskEvent> lsnr = new GridPredicate<GridTaskEvent>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(GridTaskEvent evt) {
        // Process event.
        ...

        return true; // Return true to continue listening.
    }
};

// Register event listener for all local task execution events.
g.events().localListen(lsnr, EVTS_TASK_EXECUTION);
```

Also, you should take a look at event examples shipped with GridGain:

- [EventsApiExample](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/events/EventsApiExample.java) (dead link)
- [EventsExample](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain-advanced-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/events/EventsExample.java) (possible replacement link)
- [CacheEventsExample](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/CacheEventsExample.java)

Comment: Yes, I did add a listener that I hooked into the lifecycle. I'll try to debug a bit further.  

`private void registerGridEventListener() {
        grid().events().localListen(new GridPredicate<GridEvent>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(GridEvent gridEvent) {                
                //register node monitor
                monitor().onEvent(gridEvent);
                return true;
            }
        },
                GridEventType.EVT_NODE_JOINED,
.....
                GridEventType.EVT_NODE_RECONNECTED
        );
    }`

Comment: Fixed. The previous implementation of the listener lived in the bean "gridNodeMonitor" that wasn't being registered anymore in that specific context because the property localEventListeners no longer exists. I decided to initialize the listener by hooking it into our impl. of the  GridLifecycleBean.onLifecycleEvent(AFTER_GRID_START) method. 

Thanks